# Handling 401 unauthorised error in axios react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I want to handle 401 unauthorised error when my server outputs it , I want to dispatch a action in order to do that . I am seeing that many are using axios.interceptors how do I go about it . what are interceptors? Please explain in detail as to what it is and help me . Im new to react-redux framework.  Here is my route handler in express:

```
router.get('/api/me', function(req, res) {

        if(req.user) {
            res.status(200).send({
                email : req.user.local.email,
                isCurrentUser: true
            });
        }else {
            res.status(401).send({
                isCurrentUser: false
            })
        }



})
```

here is my async action creator:

```
export const fetchCurrentUser =  () => {

    return async (dispatch) => {

        const res =  await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/me`); 
        if(res.status === 200) {
              dispatch({ type: types.YES_FETCH_CURRENT_USER, payload: res.data });
        }else if(res.status === 401) {
             dispatch({type: types.NO_FETCH_CURRENT_USER})
        }


    }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interceptors are something within `axios`. You can compare interceptors to middlewares within express. You use interceptors to

- intercept a request before it's being performed.
- intercept a response before it's being handled as a Promise by you.

Documentation about its usage can be found [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors).

In your case you could do something like:

```
const aiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // dispatch something to your store
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)

axiosInstance.get(`${ROOT_URL}/me`);
```

The above example does mean that you have to import your redux store instance to directly dispatch an action on that.

**Editted** my answer based on the below conversation:

Try:

```
export const fetchCurrentUser =  () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/me`); 

    dispatch({ type: types.YES_FETCH_CURRENT_USER, payload: res.data });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({type: types.NO_FETCH_CURRENT_USER})
  }
};
```

Comment: I dont want use interceptors can you show code where you make direct axios request

Comment: I tried this :  
export const fetchCurrentUser =  () => {
    
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
        const res =  await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/me`); 
        if(res.status === 200) {
              dispatch({ type: types.YES_FETCH_CURRENT_USER, payload: res.data });
            }
        }
        catch(error) {
            if(error.response.status === 401) {
                dispatch({type: types.NO_FETCH_CURRENT_USER})
            }
            
        }
    }
   
};

Comment: I am still getting following error in console : GET http://localhost:5000/api/me 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Your question stated what interceptors are. It seems like you're having a different problem than what you described as a question.

Your front-end is currently perfectly fine. 

In your back-end, you're checking on `req.user` - but the 'user' property isn't set by default on the `req` parameter. So your if-condition returns false, which results in you getting a `401` response.

Comment: Are you using middleware in express to set `req.user` variable?

Comment: I am doing authentication using passport-local . So when user logged in the req.user will not be undefined , basically I want to show isCurrentUser = true when user is logged in and throw error with 401 unauthorised when user is not logged in and then handle that properly(which I am struggling) with axios

Comment: So I want help with axios part where I dispatch appropriate actions based on express output

Comment: its working but I am still getting a console error: xhr.js:173 GET http://localhost:5000/api/me 401 (Unauthorized) in console . Am i unknowingly console.log(error) somehwere?

Comment: is there a way to not get that error in console.log() its pretty annoying

Comment: Networking errors are logged in your console by default, by each browser. I suggest searching for ways to handle that in a different stack overflow post as it's a different topic. Glad it's working now though :-)